# How to update cookies stored in chrome-user-profile at any time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

### Situation

I'm trying to store cookies from a browser session with Selenium.
Since I don't want to reinvent the wheel by getting and pickling the cookies I opted for using the native functionality by providing the `user-data-dir=user_profile` argument to the chrome webdriver.
This saves all the related user data in the specified directory `user_profile` to be able to reuse it next time the program runs.

This is working fine and cookies are getting stored automatically in an sql-lite file in `user_profile/Default/Cookies`

### Code

```
from selenium import webdriver as wb
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=user_profile')
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True) # Keeps the browser window open after program exits

driver = wb.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('some_url')
```

### Issue

After visiting a page the cookies are getting stored automatically as mentioned. This all happens under the hood by Selenium.
**Here is the issue**: after I log in the session cookies, which I would need to login in automatically next time, are getting triggered however those are no longer added automatically to the sql-lite file and I haven't found a way to trigger updating the existing cookies with the new ones.

How would I be able to trigger updating them?

Grateful for any suggestions.

### Update

Apparently the cookies get added automatically. But each time I start the program the created user profiles and folder gets flushed and removes the session cookies I wanted to keep.

Additionally the `.add_cookie()` method of the `webdriver` adds the cookies which are also getting stored in the sqlite file.

So the issues persist in keeping/persisting the previous session cookies without auto flushing them every time.

I tried:

```
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=user_profile')
options.add_argument('profile-directory=profile1')
```

But without success, still gets flushed.